# Twitter Bootstrap navbar float right moves div to new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I'm trying to create a section on the right of the navbar. I used the div class navbar-right which should float the div to the right, but I am getting a new line instead.

See below for code & thanks!

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">xxx</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="navbar-right">
      <p>
        <b> '.$username.' </b> | Access Level: '.$level.' | <a href=logout.php>Logout</a>
      </p> 


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Would you please accept [KyleMit's anser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18902838/1836143), as it is clearly the right one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to be placed at the top level of nav-bar, the contents must be placed inside of a div with the class: `navbar-header`

So instead of declaring the logout link inside of the div:

```html
<div class="navbar-right">
```

Use the following classes instead:

```
<div class="navbar-header pull-right">
```

Since you'll want the `Brand` to `pull-left`, you can place two `navbar-header` divs right next to each other at the very top and have one pull to each direction. Like this:

```
<div class="navbar-header pull-left">     
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">xxx</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-header pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <p class="navbar-text">
        <b> '.$username.' </b>
        <a href="logout.php" class="navbar-link">Logout</a>&nbsp;
    </p>  
</div>
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/RxguB/)

**Expanded**

[image: expanded]

**Collapsed**

[image: collapsed]

**Update**: 
As per Ram's comment, in order to not have the pull down menu not overlap on a small screen, you'll have to clear the left float like this:

```css
.navbar-collapse.in,
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have quick question. How to fix the navbar-collapse menu in mobile view which now overlaps the navbar header instead of being displayed below it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of,

```
<div class="navbar-right">
  <p>
    <b> '.$username.' </b> | Access Level: '.$level.' | <a href=logout.php>Logout</a>
  </p> 
</div>
```

Use,

```
<p class="pull-right">
    <b> '.$username.' </b> | Access Level: '.$level.' | <a href=logout.php>Logout</a>
</p>
```