# Bootstrap3 Navbar fill content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I would like to fit navbar options in all the container like this:

[image]

Tried using this website methods, but couldn't get it working, it broke my responsive.
Can anyone please explain me best way using bootstrap?
Thank you

Comment: Please do not link to an image that may disappear as it will make you question impossible to understand in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a fiddle for you take a look, it may help you.

### use margin for doing this

```
  .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
        margin: 6px 10px 0px 5px;
    }
    #blue{background-color:blue !important;    height: 57px;}
```

---

```css
.navbar-collapse.in,
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    clear: left;
}
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
    margin: 6px 10px 0px 5px;
}
#blue{background-color:blue !important;    height: 57px;}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="blue">


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
          
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">     
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">xxx</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            
          <p class="navbar-text">
            <b> '.$username.' </b>
            <a href="logout.php" class="navbar-link">Logout</a>&nbsp;
          </p>  
        </div>
          
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>


<!-- Post Info -->
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;    
            background:lightgray;width:100%;'>
     About this SO Question: <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/q/18900593/1366033'>navbar float right moves div to new line</a><br/>
     Find documentation: <a href='http://getbootstrap.com/css/'>Get Bootstrap 3.0</a><br/>
    Fork This Skeleton Here <a href='http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/'>Bootrsap 3.0 Skeleton</a><br/>
    External JS File: <a href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'>bootstrap.min.js</a><br/>
    External Style Sheet: <a href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'>bootstrap.min.css</a><br/>
    External Fonts / Icons: <a href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css'>font-awesome.min.css</a>
<div>
</div>
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/290/)